Cannot Reuse Unique Name from a Deleted Decision Matrix
A deployer was having issues moving a Business Rules Engine Lookup Table (Decision Matrix), so they deleted the one from the environment. Now, we can't deploy that decision matrix, and we can't even create a decision matrix in that environment with the deleted one's unique name.

A soql query shows that there is no decision matrix with that unique name. We were able to create a new one with a different unique name, but we are also unable to edit the unique name back to what it should be, getting this same generic error: Error saving record: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: Cannot update definition record.
The closest help I could find was this, but it doesn't really address the problem.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395023&type=1
We were able to adjust all environments to a new unique name to get around this, but I'm still wondering if anyone has some insight on where this unique name is stored, and how to truly clear out the unique name so it can be reused.

Found it... Per that article, there is a table called DecisionMatrixDefinition (which does not show up in the Object Manager.) That has the ghost row in it. To delete from it, we needed to check the "Use Tooling API" checkbox on the Developer Console rather than use normal delete[...] anon execution. Also had to remove all references to it. Hopefully this helps someone else, but in retrospect the short article actually says everything you need to know, if you know what it means!
